# Merging different data frames with different columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2, merge

I tried with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

other <- read.table(text='Phase Year    V14 V15
Other   2017    0.016488414 0.027183601
Other   2016    0.016937669 0.016937669
Other   2016    0.020214521 0.010313531
Other   2016    0.025205761 0.099279835
Other   2016    0.014341085 0.037596899
Other   2016    0.01622807  0.04254386', header=TRUE)


code <- read.table(text='Phase   Year    V5  V8  V19 V21
Code    2017    0.016488414 0.053921569 0.01114082  0.027183601
Code    2016    0.033197832 0.016937669 0.016937669 0.016937669', header=TRUE)

test <- read.table(text='Phase   Year    V6  V11 V20 V22
Test    2017    0.032531194 0.027183601 0.016488414 0.305258467
Test    2016    0.106368564 0.025067751 0.016937669 0.025067751', header=TRUE)

# tidy data
code_df <- code %>%
          gather(key, value, V5, V8, V19, V21)
test_df <- test %>%
          gather(key, value, V6, V11, V20, V22)
other_df <- other %>%
          gather(key, value, V14, V15)


newd <- merge(other_df, code_df, test_df, all=TRUE)
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
ggplot(data=newd, aes(x=Year)) +
  geom_density(aes(group=Phase, color=Phase, fill=Phase, showguide=FALSE)) +
  ggtitle("Test")+
  xlab("Year")+
  ylab("Probability")+
  facet_wrap(~Phase, ncol=1)
```

My results does not look promising, I would like to plot my data set without loosing any of them after the merging, because I want each data frame in a separated graph, but all the same in the same frame. Does any one have an idea about what what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by posting your dataset with `dput(df)`

Comment: I don't get it? what do yo mean?

Comment: See this to learn how to make good R reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @ycw thank you for that help, I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just trying to bind the columns together based on both `Phase` and `Year`. The `dplyr` approach would be.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df1 %>%
  bind_cols(df2, by = c("Phase", "Year")) %>%
  bind_cols(df3, by = c("Phase", "Year"))
```

### Edit

I now see with your gather that you are building a long format, so we'll switch to `bind_rows` to bring together.

```
newd <- bind_rows(other_df, code_df, test_df)
```

Your plot will now generate after changing that line.

[image]

Comment: It gives me an error `Error in list_or_dots(...) : object 'Phase' not found
`

Comment: @Sultan, your question is not reproducible, I have no way of knowing what contributed to your error.

Comment: How to make it reproducible, I really got confused

Comment: @Sultan, there was a link posted above by ycw that details how to do it right.

Comment: @Sultan, I have edited with quoted variables after capturing your data. I will add to my answer so that you can see how it is done.

Comment: I have updated the question and now it is reproducible, it think.

Comment: @Sultan, that is much better. You should always make it easy for other people to help you.